# Set property if method is currently running

Tags: c#, methods, properties

So I have a class containing following property:

```
public bool Busy { get; set; }
```

In the same class I have a bunch of asynchronous methods.

What I want to achieve is automatically set `Busy` property to `true` if any method in the class is being currently running, then set it back to `false` once methods returns.

Normally I would do it like that:

```
public async Task SampleMethod()
{
    Busy = true;

    // method code
    // [...]

    Busy = false;
}
```

But I wonder, if there is a way to do it for all methods in the class automatically?

Comment: Nothing automatic. Perhaps you can implement a Fody Weaver (or some AoP technique) to do "inject" the behavior at compile time.

Comment: Maybe attributes at least?

Comment: Take a look at PostSharp: http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator